# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to register a listener to an EventBus (Google Guava)

Tags: java, guava, noclassdeffounderror, event-bus

In a project for college we have to implement participants which can exchange messages via a channel. This channel has to be realised as a EventBus (Guava).

When I'm trying to register a listener (part1) to the eventbus (channel):

`channel.register(part1);`

the following Exception appears in the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3472)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3476)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2134)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry.getAnnotatedMethods(SubscriberRegistry.java:173)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry.findAllSubscribers(SubscriberRegistry.java:164)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry.register(SubscriberRegistry.java:74)
    at com.google.common/com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:186)
    at commands.Commands.createChannel(Commands.java:243)
    at persistence.HSQLDB.resetDatabase(HSQLDB.java:482)
    at gui.GUI.start(GUI.java:101)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 55 more
```

Can anyone help me?

The guava.jar is added as a library. It has to be something with the implementation of the jar and the ClassLoader.

Comment: Please add more information about the structure of your application. Does this happen at compile time or runtime? Don't you use Maven/Gradle etc? Does it happen at your localhost or at production? Which server do you use etc.?

Comment: We aren't allowed to use Maven or Gradle, but the answer from Chris solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Guava has one real dependency that is needed at runtime: `com.google.guava:failureaccess`.](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild#what-about-guavas-own-dependencies)

You'll need to [download that jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/) and put it on your classpath, too.

(As Onur Baştürk suggests, this happens automatically with some build tools.)